# java pattern match radius client in clients.conf

Tags: java, sed

I want to get all radius client in clients.conf. I have tried to use `sed`, but my `java` code failed to execute `sed`, how to use `java` pattern match to do the same thing?

```
sed -n '/^[^#]lient \([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/,/}/{p}' /home/clients.conf

client 172.1.1.0/24 {
secret          = bgate
}
```

Or, maybe someone can tell me what's wrong with my `java` code to execute `sed`?

```
String[] cmdArray = {"sed", "-n", "'/^[^#]lient \\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\.\\)\\{3\\}[0-9]\\{1,3\\}/,/}/{p}'","/home/clients.conf"};
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = run.exec(cmdArray);
```

Comment: Please share your input and expected output file.

Comment: `#client 192.168.0.0/24 {
#       secret          = testing123-1
#       shortname       = private-network-1
#}
#

client 123.168.238.5 {
secret          = bgate
}

client 172.1.1.0/24 {
secret          = bgate
}` i want to get all the valid client configuration

client 123.168.238.5 {
secret          = bgate
}

client 172.1.1.0/24 {
secret          = bgate
}

Answer (score 0):

Finally got java to excute sed,turned out i have to use bash -c.
String[] cmdArray = {"bash","-c","sed -n '/^[^#]lient \([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/,/}/{p}' /home/clients.conf"};

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
sed 's/}/}\n/g' f
```

And further you can filter as per your filter criteria.

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial to do this in Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class Clients {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^#]lient +[0-9./]+ +\\{");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        String line;
        boolean inConfig = false;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
                inConfig = true;
            }
            if (inConfig) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            if (line.startsWith("}")) {
                inConfig = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```